# @login_required causing issues

Tags: python, django, django-views

Good day, I have the following views:

```
class BookList(RequireLoginMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book/list.html'
```

and

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def fetch_book_author(request):
      context = {"context": Book.objects.all()}
      return render(request, 'book/pages/authors.html', context)

class RequireLoginMixin(object):
 @classmethod
 def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    view = super(RequireLoginMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
    return login_required(view)
```

I'm trying to deny access to all my pages except the home page. Any page that Im trying to access after applying the decorator or mixin on, is giving me the following error:

```
^__debug__/
^admin/
^mwf/
The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

Here's my urls' configuration:

```
app_name = 'bookApp'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^welcome/$', WelcomeView.as_view(), name='welcome'),
    url(r'^fetch-books/$', fetch_book_author, name='fetch'),
    url(r'^books/$', BookList.as_view(), name='books'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/mwf/'}),
    url(r'^signup/$', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

and in my settings, I have:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login/'
```

Do not know what's wrong in here.
Will really appreciate any help

Comment: It looks like the URL for login you're trying to use is `accounts/login/` but there's nothing matching that URL in urlpatterns. Try changing your login pattern to `r^'accounts/login/$'`

Comment: And use `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('login')` to avoid hard coded urls.

Comment: Did you import django.contrib.auth.views ?, also try writing 'login' instead of 'login/'

Comment: I tried it even before posting, because I couldn't figure out what was going even if  I used this r^'accounts/login/$', still having the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have either

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'  # The absolute url
```

or

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'  # the name of the url pattern.
```

The second option is better, because it avoids hardcoding the URL.

The `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting is the URL that the user is redirected to **after** they log in. It doesn't make sense to use the login url for this setting.

If you are using Django 1.9+, then you can use the [login required mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin), and you won't have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Define Login URL 
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login/' is used when you get logged into system then redirect.

Comment: Tried all of this same issue,

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and the solution.
So, since I'm using the app_name, in my urls, `app_name = 'bookApp'`, I will have to prefix any url name_space with the app_name.
So, in application:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'bookApp:login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('welcome')
```

Et voila, this does the trick.

Comment: I think that that should be `LOGIN_URL = 'bookApp:login'`.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `reverse_lazy`, so you can do `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'bookApp:welcome'`.